# Como invocar um método específico de uma classe PHP?

Tags: php, html, orientação-a-objetos, classes, método

Criei uma classe *Caneta* que tem os seguintes atributos e métodos:

```php
<?php

class caneta {
    var $modelo;
    var $cor;
    var $ponta;
    var $carga;
    var $tampada;

    function rabiscar() { 
       if ($this->tampada == true) {
           echo "<p>ERRO! Não posso rabiscar.</p>";
       }  else {
           echo "<p>Estou Rabiscando...</p>";
       }
    }

    function tampar() {
        $this->tampada = true;

    }

    function destampar() {
        $this->tampada = false;
    }
}

?>
```

Com outro arquivo `index.php`, queria saber como chamar o método `tampar()` da classe *caneta*, por exemplo, usando `onClick` em um botão, sendo assim, quando o usuário clicar no botão o método `tampar()` é invocado e o valor do atributo *tampada* muda para true.

Qual seria o método correto para fazer isso?

Minha situação é a seguinte: Eu tenho um arquivo caneta.php, sendo que neste arquivo está uma classe chamada Caneta e essa classe tem o atributo tampada, o método tampar() e o método getTampar (isto é, retorna o estado da caneta: tampada ou destampada):

```
class Caneta {
   public $tampada;
   public function tampar() {
       $this->tampada = true;
   }
   public function getTampada() {
   if ($this->tampada == true) {
       return "Tampada";
   } else {
       return "Destampada";
    }
 }  
}
```

Dentro de outro arquivo index.php eu tenho uma tag *a* e um objeto instanciado da classe caneta:

```
<?php
  require_once 'caneta.php';
  $caneta = new Caneta;
  echo '<a href = "#" id = "a" onclick = "ChamarMetodoTampar()">Tampar 
  caneta</a>';
  echo 'A caneta está {$caneta->getTampada}.';
?>
```

A minha dúvida é: como chamar o método *Tampar* da classe caneta com a propriedade onclick, fazendo assim com que o texto contido no echo mude?

Comment: O fato de estar trabalhando com onclick de um botão indica que você possui uma interface gráfica, possivelmente escrita em HTML. Se assim for, há muitos aspectos envolvidos no seu problema que não ficaram claros, pois demandará que você trate o evento no DOM da sua interface com JavaScript e se comunique de algum modo com o seu servidor rodando o PHP. Como é iniciante, não podemos supor que você já sabe fazer tudo isso, então o problema deixaria de ser apenas sobre PHP e orientação a objetos (que nem isso é na verdade, somente criar uma classe não implica em estar utilizando POO).

Comment: Por que não tenta primeiro fazer somente com PHP e depois, já dominando essa parte, fazer a integração com a interface gráfica?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, eu estou criando este site em html com PHP. Atualizei minha pergunta para ficar mais esclarecida. Talvez não seja POO, mas quando comecei a estudar sobre PHP, foi pesquisando sobre POO (desculpe minha falta de conhecimento), enfim, pesquisei sobre como fazer isso e somente encontrei fazer isso via AJAX , mas não sei como aplicar o AJAX para o meu código e nem que alterações devo fazer.

Answer (score 0):

Uma coisa muito importante que acaba não sendo mencionada quando se trabalha com PHP é que toda requisição HTTP é uma requisição SEM ESTADO, ou seja, tudo o que você faz naquela requisição, se não for persistida em um banco de dados ou em uma variável de ambiente ou em um arquivo será perdido, exemplo:

supondo que você tenha um index.php que tenha o objetivo caneta E um arquivo chamado ver_resultado.php que também usa o objeto caneta, em cada página é um objeto diferente então, se você "fechar a caneta" no index ela não vai fechar no ver_resultado!

Esse é um erro bastante comum, então assim, o que você pode fazer para testar se isso está funcionando corretamente ou não seria o seguinte:

```
<? 
require_once "caneta.php";
$caneta = new caneta();
$caneta->tampar();

// aqui vai dar erro pois a caneta foi previamente tampada
$caneta->rabiscar();
?>
```

você deve acessar diretamente a url do seu arquivo php de teste, sem tentar fazer isso via botão HTML, pois como disse o HTTP é um protocolo SEM estado.